# Error on deploying Sample data chmod()

Tags: magento2, sample-data

I had a fresh install of Magento2 and was trying to install sample data by `bin/magento sampledata:deploy` but it gave back error `In PluginManager.php(196) : eval()'d code line 188:
chmod(): Operation not permitted` . There is an error during sample data deployment. Composer file will be reverted .

Do somebody know what have gone wrong  ?

Comment: i think permission issues try this `chmod -R 777 var generated` after run this  `php bin/magento sampledata:deploy - f`

Comment: @MohitPatel Tried , but not working ....... the very same error again